# how to keep all field also do a $elemMatch projection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Below is the document:

```
{
    name:"james",
    files:[
        {name:"file1.txt", content:"..."},
        {name:"file2.txt", content:"..."},
        {name:"file3.txt", content:"..."}
    ],
    status:4
}
```

Want to make a query and return:

1. all root fields include `files`
2. `files` only contain `file2.txt` info, coze `content` is very big, only interested in `files2.txt`

I know using `$elemMatch` in find query, as below:

```
db.collection.find(
    {'files':{$elemMatch:{name:'file2.txt'}} }, 
    {name:1, status:1, 'files.$':1 } 
)
```

Is there any way to avoid list all the fields in projection and get all the key?

Requirement: **ask for all field but not to list the key** (don't list `name:1, status:1`)

Comment: What are you asking for here? How to include both `name` and `status` as well? Ask for them in the projection of course. MongoDB "projection" is "all or nothing", so if you don't ask for it you don't get it. There is no equivalent of SQL `*` in this case. Ask for **all** the fields you want. [Pretty clearly covered in the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), with the exception being of course [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you asking for namely, return all the fields, but for the `files` field return only "`files2.txt`" value ?

```
db.collection.find({ 'files':{$elemMatch:{name:'file2.txt'}} }, { 'files.$':1, name:1, status:1 } )
```